# Simple yet fast deployment tool or solution for FTP-based server

Tags: deployment, automation, ftp

I have a simple task to which some simple solution should exist yet I cannot come across one.

I have a huge file tree on computer A (development). I have the same (multiple) such file trees on a computer B (let's call it production). Computer B runs FTP and PHP, nothing much else.
I need to move the changed files from the tree on A to the tree on B but as efficiently as possible. I.e. if just one file changes, it will just transfer that one file. It would be enough to "compare" the local and remote trees using last modification dates, nothing else needed.

I tried to use the good old Ant for it but that really does not work as the FTP task is really bad one there (does not preserve modification dates on PUT and so on). What other options are there if I do not want to write the code for such a task myself? I'd expect there is some tool out there that would make a remote dir listing, download it to local computer, select only those changed files and transfer them to the destination. Do you know how I could do it? Some sort of FTP or PHP-based distributed robocopy?

EDIT: I should have added that I mean doing it on a Windows 10 computer syncing to some FTP/PHP server using command-line automated script, not GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I solved the issue using winscp. I managed to integrate it into ant calling it through the  task and using the winscp's synchronize command. For my current folder size it is fast enough, let's see later. The FTP command in ant was not useful since it does not preserve the modification dates.